# Android Library project throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lrx/Observer

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a library which makes use of Rx and I am packing this library as an aar which can be used in other projects. I am able to generate the aar but when I try to access it in other projects, it throws
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lrx/Observer;

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "rx.Observer" on path: DexPathList

Maybe I am writing the build.gradle wrong or not excluding some things. Any help is much appreciated.

My library's build.gradle looks like this

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14
```

'

Can we use Rx in a library project and export it as an aar? Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Adding the full gradle file.

Library Gradle File:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.5.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude '.readme'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/README.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
//    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.2.7.0'

    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Proguard File:

```
# Dagger
-dontwarn dagger.internal.codegen.**
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @javax.inject.* *;
    @dagger.* *;
    <init>();
}
-keep class dagger.* { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.Binding
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.ModuleAdapter
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.StaticInjection
```

*** EDIT ***

Updated gradle file for the library project

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.7'
compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.2.7.0'
```

Update proguard-rules.pro

```
# Dagger
-dontwarn dagger.internal.codegen.**
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @javax.inject.* *;
    @dagger.* *;
    <init>();
}
-keep class dagger.* { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.Binding
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.ModuleAdapter
-keep class * extends dagger.internal.StaticInjection

-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode;
}

-dontnote rx.internal.util.PlatformDependent
```

I am adding this the generated aar as a module, which is a dependency for another app.

I am still getting this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lrx/Observer;
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file

Comment: added gradle and proguard file

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode;
}

-dontnote rx.internal.util.PlatformDependent
```

See https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/RxJavaProGuardRules for more detail.

to your proguard file.

PS: You're using a very old version of RxJava. You might want to upgrade to version 1.2.7 or even RxJava2.

Edit: You also may need to add something like

```
compile ('com.somepackage:LIBRARY_NAME:1.0.0@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```

instead of just

```
compile ('com.somepackage:LIBRARY_NAME:1.0.0@aar')
```

in the build.gradle file of the project using the aar. This tells gradle to download any dependencies needed for your aar.

Comment: Thanks! I tired adding those rules and it is still being packaged in the aar.

Comment: How are you including the aar in the project that uses the library?

Comment: New->Module->Import AAR/Jar. I am using the recommended way.  So, there is a new module with the aar and a gradle file inside that module.

Gradle file looks like this:

`
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('flashsdk-debug.aar'))
`

Comment: I tried including transitive=true. It is not downloading any dependencies.